# Conditionally show a different view controller depending if User is logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, twitter-oauth

I am building an app using the Parse Library and trying to *integrate Twitter auth*. As Parse caches if a user is already logged in using

`if ([PFUser currentUser])`

I would like to show a different `UIViewController` depending if they are already logged in.

What is the best practice for this in iOS development, should I perform the checks in appDelegate or in some `NavigationController`.

How would I perform this in code?

Comment: How are you building your app storyboards or nib file or via code?

Comment: Im currently using Storyboards

Comment: Although Im totally willing to do it in code if that is easier I would prefer to write my apps without using Interface builder anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The one of the solution is that you can add one view controller (root VC) as a home page where you check if the user is logged and base on the value you can call `performSegue...` method with different identifier depends on the value.

It will require add two view controllers in storyboard one for logged and one when the user is not logged and create two segue from the home VC to those views. You need to also named the segue differently, you will be passing the name to the `performSegue...` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would lay out your storyboard with segue in the following way;

```
  navController->loginController->mainController;
```

Assign an identifier to the mainController in Interface Builder. we'll call it mainVC for the purpose of this exercise. In viewDidLoad for the loginController, you can validate the user and transition to the mainController if the user is already authenticated.

```
  E.G.

  - (void)viewDidLoad{
      [super viewDidLoad];
      /// validate  authentication status
      if([PFUser currentUser]){
         UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
         UIViewController *targetViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainVC"];
         UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

        if (navController) {
            [navController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:NO];
        }
     }
  }
```

This will display the mainViewController without stopping for authentication.